# PhoneGap iOS add UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I wish to add a UIViewController to my iOS PhoneGap application which will be loaded before
the UIWebView is loaded - some kind of splash screen which will play a video, before the actual web page is loaded.

Is that possible using PhoneGap? can someone share their experience doing something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in a regular phonegap project because you can't call a plugin until the device is ready, and that happens after showing the phonegap view.

But you can create a native project, create the first view controller and then change to a second view controller with a phonegap webview embedded

For more info about embedding phonegap webviews in native project see [cleaver doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS)